# ViewPager image doesn't appear until I swipe 2times to right or left

Tags: android, android-appcompat

ViewPager image doesn't appear until I swipe 2times to right or left
i use app appcompat 7v latest version

my image show when i swipe two swipe and when back to position my image was load.

```
public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity

{``

Context    context;
DataSource datasource;
ViewPager  pager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);

    context = this;
    datasource = new DataSource(this);

    final PageIndicator indicator = (PageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int index) {}


        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int startIndex, float percent, int pixel) {
            indicator.setPercent(percent);
            //                Log.i("LOG", "Percent: " + startIndex + ", " + percent);
            indicator.setCurrentPage(startIndex);
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    });

    Resources r = getResources();
    float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, AppConstant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    int columnWidth = (int) ((getScreenWidth() - ((AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

    String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
    String position = getIntent().getExtras().getString("position");
    String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
    //        Toast.makeText(context, position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    int pos = Integer.parseInt(position);
    //        ArrayList<StructureImage2> images = datasource.getGalleryImage2(id);
    ArrayList<String> img = datasource.getGalleryImage3(id);
    ArrayList<Integer> img4 = datasource.getGalleryImage4(id);
    GalleryImageAdapter adapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this, this, img, img4, 100);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    //        ImageLoader imageloader = new ImageLoader(context);
    //        View view = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
    //        ImageView imageofsample = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageofsample);
    //        imageloader.DisplayImage(G.context.getString(R.string.gallery_image_link) + img.get(pos), imageofsample, 200);
}
```

and in my image adpter it it my code
my galleryimageadaptercode

```
public class GalleryImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context            context;
ArrayList<String>  array;
ArrayList<Integer> intarray;
Activity           activity;
ImageLoader        imageloader;
int                columnWidth;


public GalleryImageAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList<String> array, ArrayList<Integer> intarray, int columnWidthe) {
    this.context = context;
    this.array = array;
    this.intarray = intarray;
    this.activity = activity;
    imageloader = new ImageLoader(context);
    this.columnWidth = columnWidth;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return array.size();
}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

    return view.equals(object);
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);

    ImageView imageofsample = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageofsample);
    TextView textofsample = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textofsample);

    imageloader.DisplayImage(G.context.getString(R.string.gallery_image_link) + array.get(position), imageofsample, 200);
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
```

}//end of GalleryImageAdapter

Comment: no body cant help me !

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GalleryImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<String> array;
        ArrayList<Integer> intarray;
        Activity           activity;
        ImageLoader        imageloader;
        int                columnWidth;
        List<View> viewlist = new ArrayList();


        public GalleryImageAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList<String> array, ArrayList<Integer> intarray, int columnWidthe) {
            this.context = context;
            this.array = array;
            this.intarray = intarray;
            this.activity = activity;
            imageloader = new ImageLoader(context);
            this.columnWidth = columnWidth;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return array.size();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

            return view ==  object;
        }


        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View view = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);

            ImageView imageofsample = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageofsample);
            TextView textofsample = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textofsample);

            imageloader.DisplayImage(G.context.getString(R.string.gallery_image_link) + array.get(position), imageofsample, 200);
            container.addView(view,position);
            viewlist.add(position,view);
            return view;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
//          container.removeView((View) object);
            container.removeView(viewlist.get(position));
        }

    }
```

Comment: my image load after 2 swipe yet ):

Comment: Where do you setAdapter?

Comment: in a  GalleryImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter

Comment: GalleryImageAdapter adapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this, this, arraylistofimages, 100);